# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyMySQL' Mac OSX

Tags: macos, pymysql

I am on Mac OSX (High Sierra, v 10.13.4)

I have installed the package pymysql successfully through command line. However, when I try to import pymysql in Jupyter Notebook (or in Visual Studio Code), I get the following error:

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      3 
      4 # PyMySQL
----> 5 import PyMySQL
      6 #pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyMySQL'

Does anyone know what the problem could be? Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but I managed to solve this problem by going to Anaconda Navigator and checking that pymysql was installed in all of the environments I had running. When I installed it in the correct environment, everything worked. Hope that helps someone!

Comment: You are supposed to install the module in the environment you are running the jupyter notebook. Only then it can import the pymysql module.